# How do i save individual lines from a text file in an array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

i'm taking a programming class in C and 
i am trying to make a dictionary with symbols and letters for a program ex. A = ?, B =! and so on.

the letter and it's defined symbol are saved in a text file, each in a line so:

```
A ?

B !

C =

D &
```

etc...

i'm using `FILE * fPointer` and `gets` to read and save line by line with a while loop, 
i want to save each line in an array :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE * fPointer;
    fPointer = fopen("symbols.txt", "r");
    char line[50];
    char vocab[36];
    while(!feof(fPointer))
    {
        for(int i=0;i<=36;i++)
        {
            fgets(line, 50, fPointer);
            vocab[i] = line;
            printf("%s", vocab[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, it would be saving each line in the array position
vocab[0] = "A ?"
vocab[1] = "B !"
...

It gives me the next warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast,

Comment: You can't just assign one string to another and get a deep copy, and you certainly can't assign one entire array of `char` to the single `char` you get from `vocab[i]`. So the error is totally correct. A single `char` is an integer, and an array of `char` is (or rather, decays to) a pointer. I suggest researching multi-dimensional arrays and `strcpy()`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: @screaiking You should not use `while(!feof(fPointer))`. It is considered as very bad style, look at the link Yunnosch has posted. Rather do it in the kind of `while((c = getchar(fPointer)) != EOF)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fgets` directly instead `feof` as the following:

```
#define LINES 10
#define CHARS 30

char content[LINES][CHARS];
FILE *file;
unsigned int i = 0;
file = fopen("c:\\file.txt", "r");
while ((fgets(content[i], CHARS, file)) != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", content[i]);
        i++;
}
fclose(file);
```

Comment: An extra controlling expression, `i < LINES`, wouldn't hurt.